# How do i set the android path for netbeans/cordova/windows?

Tags: android, netbeans, cordova

I have installed netbeans 7.4 and like to test cordova. For this i first need to run cordova from command line. I was able to creat the files. I am following http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface.
But when i try to build from the command line i am getting the error

> The command android failed.......make sure.....Android SDK
>   installed...to your path

I have add this to my enviroment variables as path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Within netbeans creating a cordova project doesn't work am getting the message

> Netbeans cannot find cordova or git on your path

Any tips, suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Don’t do that,try this instead

Enviroment variables should be like this:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools

then restart your cmd .

The second question I think maybe you should config cordova  and git in Netbeans.

Comment: tx yuetingqian. At the moment i have cordova running and emulating a simple helloworld from cordova cmd line, but still no luck with netbeans. I have 1/move the adt-bundle with the tools and platform-tools to c:\ 2/ i have added the tools, platform-tools paths to enviroments variable. 3/add variable JAVA_HOME and the paths to JDK. After these setting i am able to get the cordova emulate the android app. Now to add this to netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Copy the location of the Android SDK:

If you have installed Android Studio: 
(Ctrl+Alt+S) File->Settings->Appearance&Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK> Android SDK Location

In Windows 10, you have to point to the sdk folder in the **AppData**:
    C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it's a bit late... But for any others with this same issue (I spent hours on this myself), don't forget to install `Apache Ant` and set the `ANT_HOME` variable on your system also.
https://ant.apache.org/